# get autosuggestions via Bing Search API v2

Tags: bing-api

How might one be able to get the list of autosuggestions for a given search from Bing Search API like in the screen capture below?  This doesn't seem to be among the results provided by choices of `[Web|Image|Video|News|SpellingSuggestion|RelatedSearch]`.  Alternatively, does Google provide this?

As background, Bing can be queried via REST API using a query string, such as this URL (note it requires a developer key for basic auth).  One can change the 'Web' keyword to get other results, but I'd really like to get the suggestions specifically:

https://api.datamarket.azure.com/Bing/Search/Web?Query=%27sushi%27&$format=JSON&$top=5

[Bing Developer docs](https://skydrive.live.com/view.aspx?resid=9C9479871FBFA822!109&app=Word&authkey=!ACvyZ_MNtngQyCU)

[image: Bing autosuggestions]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an api route directly to the Bing suggestion list. Interestingly, this is separate from the developer API list. Currently the link is

`api.bing.com/osjson.aspx?query=[URI encoded search term here]`