# How can i get Location with name of Building use BING MAPS, ex: Eiffel Tower

Tags: c#, bing-maps

How can i get Location with name of Building use BING MAPS like fitur on google maps, 
ex: Eiffel Tower

Result : 
Latitude -> 12312.1232
Lang -> -1232,1232

I have tried ask google but got nothing, someone tell me

Comment: lol @ the irony. (did you try bing'ing it?)

Comment: First [search result](http://search.lycos.com/web?q=bing+maps+api&keyvol=008e4df4d267f84a8f03) lead me to the [Choose your Bing Maps API](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/choose-your-bing-maps-API.aspx) which lead me to [Find a Location by Query](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701711.aspx), I'd start there

Comment: any suggest?
bing-maps can get location by name of bulding right,is it?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15318150/231316

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is definitely yes for "Eiffel Tower".  Major points of landmarks like this can be found in Bing Maps. However, it should be noted that there is more than one "Eiffel Tower". In fact Bing Maps returns 3. The first is the one you likely expect and points to the tower in France. The second one points to the park in which the tower stands as it's a historic site. Then the third one points to the Eiffel tower in Paris, Tennessee: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower_(Paris,_Tennessee)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eiffel_Tower_%28Paris,_Tennessee%29)

You can test this in a couple of different ways. I used the Bing Maps REST services, but you can also do this using the search manager in the Bing Maps API. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh868062.aspx